# Belkin Nostromo Loadout Manager

Tags: mouse, gaming, keypad

How can I get the loadout Manager to see my devices?

---

Solution.  Razer Synapse Software.  I can do any of the following

- Delete Question
- Create Answer
- Leave as Is

---

- Windows 10.
- The Loadout Manager does not see my device.
  The device is not pictured and selections are inactive gray.
  Thus I cannot load a profile.
  The Nostromo Razer successfully sends default keystroke to applications such as Notepad.
- Is the software compatible with Windows 10?  It loads and runs.
- Also if it is known to work or known [not] to work that info would be useful.
- Thanks

Comment: @Ramhound Belkin and Razer labels are physically present.  Companies Collaborate.  I have done no research on that collaboration. Not all questions are perfectly articulated in my experience at StackExchange.

Comment: It was acquired in second market used.  I have not researched production history.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the loadout Manager to see my devices?

Based on the following information you would simply install the current version of Razer Synapse.

> ### Since updating to Windows 10 Razer Synapse does not detect my device and show the correct product configurator
>
> If you encounter this, please perform Synapse update through Settings >> Check for Updates. If the updates not able to run or Synapse not able to load, please uninstall Synapse and download the latest Synapse Framework from Razer support site.

Source: [RAZER NOSTROMO SUPPORT](http://support.razerzone.com/gaming-keyboards/razer-nostromo/)